# Where is the Shape located on Canvas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics

Say I put a Shape on a Canvas like this:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(myShape, 50);
Canvas.SetTop(myShape, 30);
canvas.Children.Add(myShape);
```

After that, `myShape` was drag & dropped on this Canvas.

How can I determine the current `myShape` coordinates ?

For example, before the drag & drop I would like to get (50,30).
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var left = Canvas.GetLeft(myShape);
var top = Canvas.GetTop(myShape);
```

Comment: You might want to **accept** Aviad's answer. Thanks doesn't feed his kids. ;-)

Comment: Nice, althought accepting the answer doesn't feed his kids either. My bad :-)